# iPhone database load

Tags: iphone

I have a sqlite databse that holds a table. The table contains about 7500 data. I've fetch the 7500 data in a UITableView. A UISearchBar is used to search the UITableView.There is no problem in simulator but when I run in a iPhone device, then it will take time to load and when I type to SearchBar then it hangs the device keyboard.

Is there any optimal solution to load 7500 data in a UITableView?

Comment: That may be quite a lot of data for the device to load all at once.

Can you break it down and load it in chunks as needed, and maybe implement your search to the database rather than in memory?

If it's feasible for you to move to Core Data (OS 3.0+ only), it does some batching and faulting for you instead of loading everything for the `UITableView` all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with not loading that much data at once, also I would look at optimizing your db, adding indexes, etc. Are you searching the in-memory version of the data or querying the db?  I would do the later, but would make sure that query is efficient.